# WPF InvalidOperationException Getting MainWindow Reference

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have MainWindow, which contains an instance of DemoUI (a UserControl).

From within a class instance called DemoModule, I have a reference to DemoUI which I call `_demoUI`.

When I try to get a reference to the MainWindow from within DemoModule using

`var parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(_demoUI);`

I get this `InvalidOperationException`:

`The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.`

Ultimately, I want to be able to update the MainWindow's progress bar's value using it's Dispatcher as follows:

```
var progressBar = parentWindow.FindName("ProgressBar") as ProgressBar;

progressBar.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
    new DispatcherOperationCallback(o => { 
        progressBar.Value = Progress = args.Current; 
        return null;
    }), null);
```

**Update 1**

```
public void OnProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs args)
{
    Progress = Convert.ToInt32(args.Current * 100);
    var progressBar = Application.Current.MainWindow.FindName("ProgressBar") as ProgressBar;
    if (progressBar != null)
        progressBar.Value = Progress;
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: My question is obviously about the exception.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you include here it doesn't seem like you need to get the progressBar reference in order to update the ProgressBar on your _demoUI? Is there another ProgressBar on the MainWindow? Regardless, you can use the _demoUI reference to get to the dispatcher.

```
_demoUI.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
    new DispatcherOperationCallback(o => { 
        _demoUI.ProgressBar.Value = Progress = args.Current; 
        return null;
    }), null);
```

Or

```
_demoUI.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,
    new DispatcherOperationCallback(o => { 
        var window = Window.GetWindow(_demoUI);
        //do what you need to with the window here.


    }), null);
```

Comment: Yes there is only one ProgressBar (I updated the code in my question). Also, there is no `Window.GetParent()`. If you mean `Window.GetWindow(_demoUI)` then that returns null.

Comment: Yes, sorry my mistake. Window.GetWindow. When are you calling this? Has it actually been added to the parent window already? Can you change it to BeginInvoke and set the DispatcherPriority to Background? Or Input if Background is too low of a priority?

Comment: It turns out that the WCF callback channel was running on a separate thread. I changed that behavior by commenting out `[CallbackBehavior]` and I'm also now able to get to the progress bar in the main window using the code in the update above. I don't think the WCF piece had much to do with this, but it was interesting nonetheless.